# concatenate or vstack numpy arrays doubling memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-management

**Some previous information**

I have the following method which loads two data sets from disk then combines them and returns the combined data set.

```
def _get_data(self, data_set_name):
    training_data = DataSet.from_file('path_to_data_file','path_to_label_file')
    test_data = DataSet.from_file('path_to_data_file','path_to_label_file')
    return training_data.concat(test_data) # doubles the memory consumption
```

The `DataSet`looks like this:

```
class DataSet:
  def __init__(self, data, labels):
    self.x = data # float64 array of shape (x,y)
    self.y = labels # int array of shape (x,)

  def concat(self, other_data_set):
    new_x = numpy.vstack((self.x, other_data_set.x))
    new_y = numpy.concatenate((self.y, other_data_set.y))

    return DataSet(new_x, new_y)
```

**My Problem**

When calling `DataSet.concat` the memory gets doubled. That's expected behavior in first place, since numpy creates two new arrays containing the combined data.
**BUT** after leaving the `_get_data` method, the variables `training_data` and `test_data` should no longer reference the smaller data sets.
So I expected that the memory consumption should reduce again.
This doesn't happen. Because I was wondering, I tried to call garbage collection manually without any success.

```
data_set = _get_data('someName')
gc.collect(0)
gc.collect(1)
gc.collect(2)
# Still same memory consumption
```

Can anyone explain to me what happens here? Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

I measure the memory by the following code:

```
pid = os.getpid()
py = psutil.Process(pid)
memoryUse = py.memory_info()[0] / 2. ** 30  # memory use in GB
print('memory use:', memoryUse)
```

Comment: Not sure if that helps: try to run manual collection (`gc.collect()`) three times, passing it 0, 1, and 2 respectively (to free all generations of objects).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @kazemakase. I tried but this doesn't result in any change in memory consumption.

Comment: Was just an idea ;) Btw, this could also be related to how you measure memory consumption. *Maybe* Python is not releasing the memory back to the OS but marking it as free internally?

Comment: If that's the case then it's related to my measurement, but this would be different to what python does for other operations.

Comment: I tried to allocate and `del` a numpy array and the memory was freed immediately (according to Taskmanager, on Windows/IPython). This invalidates my guess about memory not releasing back to the OS - at least in my setup. Something else may be going on here. Are you sure you do net keep any references to the original arrays?

Comment: Now it's getting "interesting". I wanted to try another way of measuring memory and used the code updated in my question.
At the first try the memory was freed after calling garbage collection manually. I was happy and almost wanted to tell you, that your guess was right. When I tried a second time the memory was NOT freed by calling garbage collection..
I'm sure that i didn't keep any references to the original arrays yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163935/discussion-between-yannic-klem-and-kazemakase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this behavior occurred because of debugging.
When I placed breakpoints before `_get_data` the memory was not freed after stepping out of `_get_data` and move on.
When I placed the first breakpoint after the call to `_get_data` memory was freed correctly.
I did not know that debugging could have such an impact on memory management.

Comment: Were all the issues related to debugging? I'm having a very similar issue, but I'm not debugging at all. I read a bunch of .npy files, append the arrays to a list, vstack the list into a a single array, and the final memory comsumption (after losing the reference to the list of arrays) is double the memory that the single array should consume. I can't figure it out why!